# Problem with packaging multiple projects within one solution in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have one solution with Web application and two windows services plus Db project. 
My goal is to have one package for every application (one web, two services, one DB project).

Right now, I use msbuild in TFS 2012 on-premise. 
I added `/p:GenerateProjectSpecificOutputFolder=True` as msbuild argument and build the solution with specific projects to create those folders. Then I run PowerShell script that packs all folder to package and pull to Octopus.

I couldn't use the same technique with Azure DevOps. Visual Studio build step allows specifying only the solution to build to. It puts all files into one drop folder.

Comment: Why not use MS Build task instead of Visual Studio build task?

Comment: Tried. You can't specify projects to build too.

Comment: What happens when you specify `csproj` file? (because I can specify `csproj` and not `sln`).

Comment: Tried. Failed with an error about output path. I tried to setup it in the project file and as msbuild arguments. Didn't work.

Comment: @DenisTsapelnikov I just had this issue and I found it was because Azure DevOps had "release" and "any cpu" as the configuration and platform. After I changed that to "Release" and "Any CPU" it picked up the output path and build ok.